# OCaml: How to build mirage-tcpip using dune?

Tags: functional-programming, network-programming, ocaml, ocaml-dune

I'm trying to build the examples at https://github.com/mirage/mirage-tcpip in the folder "examples".

First I did `opam install .`  in the root directory to install all dependencies. Then I did `dune build` and it build everything in `_build`, lots of `.a, .cma, .cmx, .cmi, .cmxa` files that I don't know what are for (**can somebody explain**?).

Anyways, I think the examples have to be built separately, because they have their own dune files. But I tried running `dune build` on them and got:

```
root@66f08fd7c55b:/workspaces/ocaml_env/mirage-tcpip/examples/ping# dune build
Entering directory '/workspaces/ocaml_env/mirage-tcpip'
root@66f08fd7c55b:/workspaces/ocaml_env/mirage-tcpip/examples/ping# ls
dune  ping.ml
root@66f08fd7c55b:/workspaces/ocaml_env/mirage-tcpip/examples/ping# cat dune 
(executables
 (names ping)
 (libraries cmdliner logs logs.fmt tcpip.icmpv4-socket))
root@66f08fd7c55b:/workspaces/ocaml_env/mirage-tcpip/examples/ping# dune build ping
Entering directory '/workspaces/ocaml_env/mirage-tcpip'
Error: Don't know how to build ping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation of OCaml file types:

Regarding the file types in the `_build` directory ([reference 1](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/native.html#s:native-overview), [reference 2](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/comp.html)):

- `.a` are standard archive files (also known as static libraries) containing native code:

  > Arguments ending in .o or .a (.obj or .lib under Windows) are assumed to be C object files and libraries. They are passed to the C linker when linking in -custom mode (see the description of -custom below).
- `.cma` are the OCaml byte code equivalent of `.a` files, so static libraries, but with platform-independent OCaml byte code instead of machine-dependent native code:

  > Arguments ending in .cma are taken to be libraries of object bytecode. A library of object bytecode packs in a single file a set of object bytecode files (.cmo files).
- `.cmx` contain meta-data for how to link native code object files together:

  > Arguments ending in .ml are taken to be source files for compilation unit implementations. ... From the file x.ml, the ocamlopt compiler produces two files: x.o, containing native object code, and x.cmx, containing extra information for linking and optimization of the clients of the unit.
- `.cmi` are compiled interface definition files:

  > Arguments ending in .mli are taken to be source files for compilation unit interfaces. Interfaces specify the names exported by compilation units: they declare value names with their types, define public data types, declare abstract data types, and so on. From the file x.mli, the ocamlopt compiler produces a compiled interface in the file x.cmi.
- `.cmxa` are native code library files that combine `.a`/`.o` and and `.cmx` files, so like `.a` but with additional linking information from the `.cmx` files:

  > Arguments ending in .cmxa are taken to be libraries of object code.

### Building the example

Regarding the build of the `ping` example, to build an executable target with `dune`, you have to append `.exe` to the target name ([reference](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick-start.html)):

> Note that native code executables will have the .exe extension on all platforms (including non-Windows systems).

So the full sequence of build commands would be:

- Install dependencies:

  ```
  $ opam install .
  ```
- Build `mirage-tcpip`:

  ```
  $ dune build
  ```
- Build the `ping` example:

  ```
  $ cd example/ping
  $ dune build ping.exe
  ```
- Run the binary:

  ```
  # dune exec ./ping.exe 8.8.8.8
  ```

  Alternatively, from the `mirage-tcpip` directory:

  ```
  # ./_build/default/examples/ping/ping.exe 8.8.8.8
  ```